# bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied (error installing Android-Studio)

Tags: android, bash, intellij-idea, android-studio

While I was trying to Install Android-Studio
and execute the command

```
@abhinay-Pc:/android-studio/bin$`./studio.sh
```

It is showing the error:

```
bash: ./studio.sh: Permission denied
```

I have already exported Java directory to `/android-studio/bin` folder`

```
(Java_Home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle)
```

I have the java-7 installed on my system.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You might not have `chmod +x studio.sh` try `sh ./studio.sh`

If this was not it, try again like this: `sh -x ./studio.sh`. This will show you every line that is run and will help you debug it.

Good luck.

Comment: This is still an issue (using Ubuntu 18.04) , the above mentioned solution does not help. Seems to be something deeper

Comment: @mcExchange 6 years later it is likely not the same problem. Please start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

you must change the properties of the studio.sh file and change in the permission to Allow this file to run as program

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with how the zipped file was unpacked. Try to unpack the zip file again using the right application and give it enough time to do so. On unpacking the second time, I realized that the second folder was more than double the size of the first unpacked folder due to a possibility of interruption of the unpacking process initially. After that, you can execute the **./studio.sh** command after changing directory (cd) to the bin folder of the android studio folder to start your application.